# yii2 migration command shows "Out of memory" error

Tags: php, laravel, yii2, out-of-memory, command-line-interface

When I call yii2 migrate command(from console). I always get "Out of memory" message. In regular case php do not show this error, but when migration command.

```
# ./yii migrate
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.13-dev)

Out of memory
```

However PHP through Apache works absolutely fine. It's just on the CLI that I get this error. The machine is running CentOS release 6 and PHP 5.6. System memory is 6GB, that is enough to run command.

```
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5971       1557       4413        128        119        440
-/+ buffers/cache:        998       4973
Swap:            0          0          0
```

**Add**:

- I witnessed laravel artisan command also show that error.
- I could not know what occurs this error finally. But when *I re-installed php library from base*, the error disappeared. This may help for you.

Comment: Seems, you have two different configs for CLI and apache mode. Check max memory usages in the first (memory_limit).

Comment: I could not know what occurs this error finally. But when I re-installed php library from base, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the PHP memory limit set for CLI commands is lower than the memory required by your migrations. You can increase the memory limit for CLI commands by adjusting the memory_limit directive in your PHP configuration file (php.ini). Set it to a higher value, such as memory_limit = 512M or memory_limit = -1